# How to Keep Previous Pandas Plots?

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I am plotting a frequency graph for each of my features in my machine learning data set. The problem is I am using pandas and the graphs are not staying when the next one is plotted.

```
for col in X_train.columns:
    if "ThreeMonthAvg" in col:
        X_train[col] = pd.cut(X_train[col], bins=[-np.inf, 0, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, np.inf])
        print(col)
        X_train[col].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

This is a for-loop I use to traverse my dataset and find the columns I want to plot. Only the last plot remains.

Any ideas on how I can keep all the plots?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to combine all the plots.

You can set up the axes and reuse it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot()

for col in X_train.columns:
    if "ThreeMonthAvg" in col:
        X_train[col] = pd.cut(X_train[col], bins=[-np.inf, 0, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, np.inf])
        print(col)
        X_train[col].value_counts().plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

Comment: What if I want separate graphs for each one?